# Magento 2 : Old product url to new product url redirect

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite, 301-redirect

1. Create a few new products. And set a URL for it (test1, test2, test3, etc.)
2. Change the URL via CSV import of that product (SKU, url_key) .. (change to 10test, 11test, 12test, etc)
   . When using the old URL in frontend it must be redirected to the new URL.
   Any help? Thank in advance.

Comment: Refer: https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215747748-How-can-I-redirect-and-rewrite-my-URLs-with-an-htaccess-file-

Answer (score 0):

To redirect from old URL to new URL, you need to remove old entries from the table url_rewrite and required to do reindexing,

Thanks,